# Clear Git Files

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

When I try to upload a file to Github or Bitbucket, there is some old file lingering on my computer that always shows up in the repository file on Github. These old files are not in the same physical directory. I am not sure how to remove it from  my 'git' system. I do not know if git filter-branch is appropriate in this example. I have tried it, but may not be using it correctly.  Can someone advise?

Comment: old files ? Did you index them any time to git ?

Comment: try git clean -nf, it will show all the untracked files that can be removed. Once confirms, use git clean -f

Comment: @VinayVeluri yes, I do believe I may have indexed them with git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the files are indexed, the process by definition indicates you are asking git to track the files.

Just do `git clean -f -d` to remove all the untracked files as they are not required now.